# draper decorator changed the 'model' attribute from original model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I am implementing draper decorators and below is the code.

```
def edit 
    find_machine!
    puts @machine.model
    authorize! :edit, @machine
end

def find_machine!
    @machine = Machine.find(params[:id])
end
```

Everything works fine before I added the `.decorate` method,

```
def find_machine!
    @machine = Machine.find(params[:id]).decorate
end

class MachineDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    delegate_all
    decorates_finders

    def test_decorate
        'please'
    end
end
```

Before I add the `.decorate` method, the @model attributes is what it suppose to be, but after I add the method, the puts output become: `#<Machine:0x007fd7e7813500>`

What happend?

Comment: what is `.model` supposed to return exactly?

Comment: `machine.model` is a string attribute in the model.